# Getting filtered all values on selectInput and reflecting it on Column plot

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm new on R and this is a bit challenging and I would like to ask for guidance and help,

I was trying to get a selectInput that could take one value of a vector (As factor) or all the elements.

Once everything was filtered I could use that selectImput data to filter the plots and arrays (Column and regular) to dynamically changing the values on those objects.

With one value changing in the SelectInput there is no problem (Example: Going in "Cuartel" from C1 to C2) but, trying to get them all (C1 & C2) just give me the first result of the unique vector in "Cuartel" or any other variable that I want to filter as expected, not all.

Edit: To clarify, in summary, when I select "All", instead of show me the summary of C1 & C2 in the plots as it should be, the results are just C1 values associated to that filter by default.

| semana | Clasifica | Cuartel | labor_agricola | unidad_trato | rendimiento | jornada | valor_dia | Tipo_Dato | Especie | Variedad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | F | C1 | P | Lt | 100 | 0.8 | 28571 | Proy | A | B |
| 24 | F | C1 | P | Lt | 100 | 0.6 | 28571 | Proy | A | B |
| 22 | F | C1 | P | Lt | 80 | 1 | 34286 | Real | A | B |
| 24 | F | C1 | P | Lt | 70 | 1 | 34286 | Real | A | B |
| 22 | F | C1 | P | Lt | 70 | 1.5 | 25714 | Per. Ant | A | B |
| 24 | F | C1 | P | Lt | 65 | 1.2 | 25714 | Per. Ant | A | B |
| 22 | F | C1 | P | Lt | 85 | 0.8 | 25571 | Acu + Proy | A | B |
| 24 | F | C1 | P | Lt | 85 | 0.6 | 25571 | Acu + Proy | A | B |
| 22 | F | C2 | P | Lt | 100 | 0.8 | 28571 | Proy | A | B |
| 24 | F | C2 | P | Lt | 100 | 0.6 | 28571 | Proy | A | B |
| 22 | F | C2 | P | Lt | 80 | 1 | 34286 | Real | A | B |
| 24 | F | C2 | P | Lt | 70 | 1 | 34286 | Real | A | B |
| 22 | F | C2 | P | Lt | 70 | 1.5 | 25714 | Per. Ant | A | B |
| 24 | F | C2 | P | Lt | 65 | 1.2 | 25714 | Per. Ant | A | B |
| 22 | F | C2 | P | Lt | 85 | 0.8 | 25571 | Acu + Proy | A | B |
| 24 | F | C2 | P | Lt | 85 | 0.6 | 25571 | Acu + Proy | A | B |

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(quantmod)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(DataCombine)
library(rvest)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(patchwork)
library(gganimate)
library(fontawesome)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)


library(openxlsx)
data <-read.xlsx("~ data.xlsx", sheet="1", skipEmptyCols=TRUE, 
        detectDates=TRUE, colNames = TRUE)
data$semana = as.factor(data$semana)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "green",
                    dashboardHeader(title="Kpis agrícolas"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      # Custom CSS to hide the default logout panel
                      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-server-account { 
                      display: none; }'))),
                      # The dynamically-generated user panel
                      uiOutput("userpanel"),
                      
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Dashboard", 
                           icon = icon("dashboard")),
                        menuItem("Tablas", tabName = "Tablas", 
                           icon = icon("th"))
                      )
                      
                      
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        
                        #Filtro de graficos
                        tabItem(tabName = "Dashboard",
                                fluidRow(
                                  column(width = 2,
                                         #Cuadro selección Clasificación
                                         selectInput(inputId = "Clasifica", 
                                                     label ="Clasificación", 
                                       append("All", 
                                       unique(data$Clasifica)), 
                                       multiple = TRUE, selected = "All")
                                  ),
                                  column(width = 2, 
                     #Cuadro selección Labor y/o unidad de medida
                                         selectInput(inputId = "Especie", 
                                             label = "Especie", 
                                             choices = append("All", 
                                             unique(data$Especie)), 
                                             multiple = TRUE, 
                                             selected = "All")
                                  ),
                                  column(width = 2, 
                  # Cuadro selección Labor y/o unidad de medida
                                  selectInput(inputId = "Variedad", 
                                         label = "Variedad", 
                                         choices = append("All", 
                                         unique(data$Variedad)), 
                                         multiple = TRUE, selected = "All")
                                  ),
                                  column(width = 2, 
             # Cuadro selección Cuartel
                                  selectInput(inputId = "Cuartel", 
                                     label = "Cuartel", 
                                     choices = append("All", 
                                     unique(data$Cuartel)), multiple = TRUE, 
                                     selected = "All")
                                  ),
                                  column(width = 2,
                     # Cuadro selección Faena
                     selectInput(inputId = "labor_agricola", 
                     label = "Faena agrícola", choices = append("All", 
                      unique(data$labor_agricola)), multiple = TRUE, 
                      selected = "All")
                                  ),
                                  column(width = 2, 
                            # Cuadro selección Labor y/o unidad de medida
                            selectInput(inputId = "unidad_trato", label = 
                            "Labor/Unidad de medida", 
                            choices = append("All", 
                                 unique(data$unidad_trato)), 
                                  multiple = TRUE, selected = "All")
                                  )
                                ),
                                
                                
                                # plotOutput("line")
                                strong("General de rendimientos"),      
                                uiOutput("RendimientosAC"),
                                fluidRow(
                                  column(6, offset=0, 
                 plotlyOutput("Rendimientos_Acumulados_Resumen", 
                  width = "100%", height = "100%")),
                  column(6, offset=0, 
                  plotlyOutput("Rendimientos_Acumulados", width = "100%", 
                    height = "100%"))
                                ),
                                br(),
                                br(),
                                
                                #plotOutput("line")
                                strong("General de valor día"),      
                                uiOutput("Valor_dia_AC"),
                                fluidRow(
                                  column(6, offset=0, 
             plotlyOutput("Valor_Dia_Resumen", width = "100%", 
              height = "100%")), column(6, offset=0, 
             plotlyOutput("Valor_Dia", width = "100%", height = "100%"))
                                ),
                        ),
                        
                        tabItem(tabName = "Tablas",
                                uiOutput("Indicadores_Cuarteles")
                        ) 
                        
                      )
                    ) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Filtros 
  observe({
    #Selector de opciones (Todas o varias)
    if("All" %in% input$Clasifica)
      Clasifica_elegido = append("All", unique(data$Clasifica))[-1]
    else
      Clasifica_elegido = input$Clasifica
    updateSelectInput(session, "Clasifica", selected = Clasifica_elegido)
    
    if("All" %in% input$Cuartel)
      Cuartel_elegido = append("All",unique(data$Cuartel))[-1]
    else
      Cuartel_elegido = input$Cuartel
    updateSelectInput(session, "Cuartel", selected = Cuartel_elegido)
    
    if("All" %in% input$labor_agricola)
      labor_agricola_elegido = append("All",unique(data$labor_agricola))[-1]
    else
      labor_agricola_elegido = input$labor_agricola
    updateSelectInput(session, "labor_agricola", 
        selected = labor_agricola_elegido)
    
    if("All" %in% input$unidad_trato)
      unidad_trato_elegido = append("All", unique(data$unidad_trato))[-1]
    else
      unidad_trato_elegido = input$unidad_trato
    updateSelectInput(session, "unidad_trato", 
     selected = unidad_trato_elegido)
    
    if("All" %in% input$Especie)
      Especie_elegido = append("All",unique(data$Especie))[-1]
    else
      Especie_elegido = input$Especie
    updateSelectInput(session, "Especie", selected = Especie_elegido)
    
    if("All" %in% input$Variedad)
      Variedad_elegido = append("All",unique(data$Variedad))[-1]
    else
      Variedad_elegido = input$Variedad
    updateSelectInput(session, "Variedad", selected = Variedad_elegido)
    
    
  })
  
  ##Indicadores de cuarteles
  
  output$Indicadores_Cuarteles <- renderTable ({
    
    Ind_Cuart <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
    Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
    unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
    Variedad == input$Variedad)
    
    Ind_Cuart <- group_by(Ind_Cuart, Clasifica, Cuartel, labor_agricola, 
     unidad_trato, Especie, Variedad) %>%
      filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, Cuartel == input$Cuartel, 
    labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, unidad_trato == 
      input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
        Variedad == input$Variedad)
    
    Ind_Cuart %>% 
      summarise(Rendimiento = sum(rendimiento))
    
    
  })
  
  
  ##Matrices de dashboard
  
  output$RendimientosAC <- renderTable ({
    
    MRend <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
    colnames(MRend) <- c('Proy','Per. Ant','Acu + Proy')
    x<- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
     Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
     unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
     Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Real") %>% 
     summarise(sum(rendimiento))
    y <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
         Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
         unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
         Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Proy") %>% 
          summarise(sum(rendimiento))
    z <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
       Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
       unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
       Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Per. Ant") %>% 
       summarise(sum(rendimiento))
    v <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
          Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
          unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
          Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Acu + Proy") %>% 
          summarise(sum(rendimiento))
    MRend[1, 1] <- paste(format(round(x/y*100, 2), nsmall = 2), "%")
    MRend[1, 2] <- paste(format(round(x/z*100, 2), nsmall = 2), "%")
    MRend[1,3]<- paste(format(round(x/v*100, 2), nsmall = 2),"%")
    MRend
  })
  
  output$Valor_dia_AC <- renderTable ({
    
    MVD <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
    colnames(MVD) <- c('Proy','Per. Ant','Acu + Proy')
    xx <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
         Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
         unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
         Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Real") %>% 
         summarise(sum(valor_dia))
    yy <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
           Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
           unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
           Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Proy") %>% 
           summarise(sum(valor_dia))
    zz <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
           Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
           unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
           Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Per. Ant") %>% 
           summarise(sum(valor_dia))
    vv <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
            Cuartel == input$Cuartel, 
            labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
            unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
            Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Acu + Proy") %>% 
    summarise(sum(valor_dia))
    MVD[1,1] <- paste(format(round(xx/yy*100, 2), nsmall = 2),"%")
    MVD[1,2] <- paste(format(round(xx/zz*100, 2), nsmall = 2),"%")
    MVD[1,3] <- paste(format(round(xx/vv*100, 2), nsmall = 2),"%")
    MVD
  })
  
  output$Vald_vs_Jorn <- renderTable ({
    
    MVDvJ <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
    colnames(MVDvJ) <- c('Proy','Per. Ant','Acu + Proy')
    xxxxx<- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
        Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
        unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
        Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Real") %>% 
        summarise(sum(jornada))
    yyyyy <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
      Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
      unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
       Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Proy") %>% 
       summarise(sum(jornada))  

    zzzzz <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
      Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
      unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
      Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Per. Ant") %>% 
        summarise(sum(jornada))
    vvvvv <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
       Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
       unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
       Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Acu + Proy") %>% 
       summarise(sum(jornada))
    xxxxxx <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
      Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
      unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
      Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Real") %>% 
        summarise(sum(valor_dia))
    yyyyyy <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
      Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
      unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
      Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Proy") %>% 
        summarise(sum(valor_dia))  

    zzzzzz <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
       Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
       unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
       Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Per. Ant") %>% 
       summarise(sum(valor_dia))  

    vvvvvv <- data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
     Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
    unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
    Variedad == input$Variedad, Tipo_Dato == "Acu + Proy") %>% 
    summarise(sum(valor_dia))

    MVDvJ[1, 1] <- paste(format(round(xxxxxx/xxxxx/yyyyyy/yyyyy*100, 2), 
                         nsmall = 2),"%")
    MVDvJ[1, 2] <- paste(format(round(xxxxxx/xxxxx/zzzzzz/zzzzz*100, 2), 
                         nsmall = 2),"%")
    MVDvJ[1, 3] <- paste(format(round(xxxxxx/xxxxx/vvvvvv/vvvvv*100, 2), 
                         nsmall = 2),"%")
    MVDvJ
  })
  
  

  output$Rendimientos_Acumulados_Resumen <- renderPlotly({
    ggplot(data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
  Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
  unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
  Variedad == input$Variedad), 
           aes(y=rendimiento, x= fct_reorder(Tipo_Dato, rendimiento, 
              .desc = TRUE), color = Tipo_Dato, fill = Tipo_Dato)) + 
  geom_col() + geom_point() + theme_bw() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", 
   decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)) + 
      labs(title = "Rendimientos - Resumen",
           subtitle = "X",
           caption = "X",
           x = "Tipo de dato", y = "Rendimiento",
           tag = "X")
  })
  

  output$Rendimientos_Acumulados <- renderPlotly({
    ggplot(data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
      Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
      unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
        Variedad == input$Variedad), 
           aes(semana, rendimiento, 
               color = Tipo_Dato, group = Tipo_Dato)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + theme_bw() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", 
     decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)) + 
      labs(title = "Rendimientos - Semana",
           subtitle = "X",
           caption = "X",
           x = "Semanas", y = "Rendimiento",
           tag = "Rendimientos")
  })
  

  output$Valor_Dia_Resumen <- renderPlotly({
    ggplot(data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
  Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
  unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
  Variedad == input$Variedad), 
           aes(y=valor_dia, x= fct_reorder(Tipo_Dato, valor_dia, 
   .desc = TRUE), color = Tipo_Dato, fill = Tipo_Dato)) + geom_col() + 
   geom_point() + theme_bw() + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", 
     decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)) + 
      labs(title = "$ - Resumen",
           subtitle = "X",
           caption = "X",
           x = "Tipo de dato", y = "$",
           tag = "X")
  })
  

  output$Valor_Dia <- renderPlotly({
    ggplot(data %>% filter(Clasifica == input$Clasifica, 
  Cuartel == input$Cuartel, labor_agricola == input$labor_agricola, 
  unidad_trato == input$unidad_trato, Especie == input$Especie, 
   Variedad == input$Variedad), 
           aes(semana, valor_dia, 
               color = Tipo_Dato, group = Tipo_Dato)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + theme_bw() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", 
     decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)) +
      labs(title = "$ - Semana",
           subtitle = "X",
           caption = "X",
           x = "Semanas", y = "$",
           tag = "X")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Using the method observe with the selectInput to form the filtering vector.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, and it's not minimal, so it's hard to help you. By the way is there any reason you are adding this 'all' option? if the user do not select any filter it would anyway show ALL so why bother adding it?

Comment: The code has been corrected to be reproducible, regarding the comment of MeisamYSF, many thanks

Comment: Hi! thanks for the comment MeisamYSF. About the "All" option, is because there is going to be elderly people using it and has to be intuitive, also for what I test, the function returns by default the first value if nothing is selected 8(

Comment: Any Help pls 8( ?